# Проигрывать анимацию ScrollIntoView Out только тогда, когда текстовый блок находится ВНЕ поле зрения пользователя (использование Blast.js)

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы анимация ScrollIntoView OUТ проигрывалась только тогда, когда текстовый блок выходит из поля зрения пользователя? Сейчас проигрывается анимация при малейшем скролле - и это ужасно.

Посмотрите собранный пример: http://just-text.webflow.io/

Сам код:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (evt) => {
  const footer = document.getElementById('spans');
  const isInView = isScrolledIntoView(spans);
  if (isInView) {
    console.log('the element is in view and should now execute your code');
    $(function() {
      var words = $('h1').blast({
        delimiter: 'word'
      });
      words.each(function(i) {
        $(this).css({
            position: 'relative',
            top: 150,
          })
          .delay(i * 70)
          .animate({
            top: '50px'
          }, 400, );
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log('the element is out of view and shouldnt execute your code');
    // TODO: If element is not in view...
  }
})

function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const elemTop = rect.top;
  const elemBottom = rect.bottom;

  return elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Богдан Гётте, установи расширение гугл переводчик, а?

> - the element is in view and should now execute your code
> - the element is out of view and shouldnt execute your code
> - // TODO: If element is not in view...

а также читай вывод консоли, и комментарии, особенно `TODO:`

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', (evt) => {
  const footer = document.getElementById('spans');
  const isInView = isScrolledIntoView(spans);
  if (isInView) {
    console.log('элемент внутри области просмтри');
  } else {
    console.log('элемент за пределами облости просмотра');
    // --
    footer.style.top = window.scrollY + 50 + 'px'
  }
})

function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const elemTop = rect.top;
  const elemBottom = rect.bottom;

  return elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="spans" style="position:absolute;top:50px">spans</div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:7000px;">fixed</div>
```

Comment: Не получается. Я не понимаю, или не туда пи вставляю. Объясните, пожалуйста, лучше. Для меня Javascript - это что-то совсем неизведанное

Comment: @БогданГётте, просто замени `footer.style.top = window.scrollY + 50 + 'px'` на свой код

Comment: спасибо! Не понимаю - почему именно туда, но еще буду разбираться в том, как устроен код. Если появится свободное время, можете подсказать, как пристроить плавность InoutExpo?

Comment: @БогданГётте, https://easings.net/ru#easeInOutExpo ; если мой ответ тебя устраивает - отметь его галочкой(как решённый) ; создавая новый аналогичный вопрос, добавь тэг  `CSS` и `JQuery`

Comment: отметил, спасибо! Я не знаю куда мне вставлять

Comment: ищи по ссылке `animate` и у себя в коде `animate`

Comment: я добавил, но ничего не вышло 600, 'easeInOutExpo', function () { … })